# How to use $_GET inside server side processing script of Datatables?

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I'm using this example's code https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

I want to use $_GET variable in the server_processing.php file so that I can specify the value and doing this from the url. For example table.php?table-id=table1

index.html

```
    <a href="table.php?table-id=table1">Table 1</a>
    <a href="table.php?table-id=table2">Table 2</a>
    <a href="table.php?table-id=table3">Table 3</a>
```

table.php

```
    <?php
    // Get
    $var = $_GET['table-id'];
    ?>
    <table id="example" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Payslip ID</th>
                <th>Employee ID</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
        } );
    } );
    </script>
```

scripts/server_processing.php

```
    <?php
    // DB table to use
    $table = '$var';

    // Table's primary key
    $primaryKey = 'id';

    // indexes
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 )
    );

    // SQL server connection information
    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => '',
        'db'   => 'sampledb',
        'host' => 'localhost'
    );

    require( 'ssp.class.php' );

    echo json_encode(
        SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    );
```

variable table-id is undefined. Is there a way to do this? The link part is important so I cannot remove that from the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value of `$_GET['table-id']` through to the AJAX call by using the [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) feature.

> The `ajax.data` option provides the ability to add additional data to the request, or to modify the data object being submitted if required.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "data": {
            "table_id": <?= $_GET['table_id'] ?>
        }
    }
} );
```

Then `$_GET['table_id']` should be available within `scripts/server_processing.php`.

Comment: Thanks. I enclosed php tag inside double quotes since I'm getting Syntax Error.
`"table_id": "<?= $_GET['table_id'] ?>" `.